# numpy vectorise value generation from a truncated gaussian distribution

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, normal-distribution, truncation

I've a function which generates a value from a truncated normal distribution, with a while loop which ensures that any generated value that lies outside the truncation gets discarded and replaced with another generation until it lies within the range.

```
def gen_truncated(minimum, maximum, ave, sigma):
    # min=0.9, max=1, 
    x = 0.
    while x < minimum or x > maximum:
        x = np.random.normal(0,1)*sigma+ave

    return x
```

How can I vectorise this function in such a way that `x` is now an array of many `x` values, generated in such a way that there's always a while loop ensuring that the array elements are regenerated so long as the condition of `x < minimum` and `x > maximum` is reached? Is there a vectorise way of comparing every element of `x` to a number i.e. `minimum` or `maximum`?

Edit:
What if I have more constraints that need to be satisfied? Ultimately I'm looking to vectorise the generation of a 4x4 matrix that's generated through several contraints, the constraint in `gen_truncated()` is just one of the many. I have a `gen_sigma()` which first generates 3 values `lambda1, lambda2, lambda3`, now `lambda3` again needs to satisfy several conditions w.r.t the values of `lambda1` and `lambda2` otherwise they get redrawn. Once they're right, all three values gets fed into `get_tau()` to generate 3 values. Again these tau values need to satisfy some more constraints, otherwise they are thrown away and are generated again until they're right. Ultimately, they form a 4x4 matrix called `sigma_gen`, which are multiplied left and right by `create_rotation()` through `gen_channel` to create a single 4x4 matrix `channel`.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm

def gen_sigma(minimum, maximum, ave, sigma):
    lambda1 = gen_truncated(minimum, maximum, ave, sigma)
    lambda2 = gen_truncated(minimum, maximum, ave, sigma)
    lambda3 = gen_truncated(minimum, maximum, ave, sigma)

    while 1+lambda3 < abs(lambda1+lambda2) or 1-lambda3 < abs(lambda2-lambda1):
        lambda3 = gen_truncated(minimum, maximum, ave, sigma)

    tau = get_tau(lambda1, lambda2, lambda3)
    lambdas = [lambda1, lambda2, lambda3]
    while (norm(tau)**2 >
           1-sum([x**2 for x in [lambda1, lambda2, lambda3]]) +
           2*lambda1*lambda2*lambda3) or (z_eta(tau, lambdas) < 0):
        tau = get_tau(lambda1, lambda2, lambda3)

    sigma_gen = np.array([[     1,       0, 0, 0],
                          [tau[0], lambda1, 0, 0],
                          [tau[1], 0, lambda2, 0],
                          [tau[2], 0, 0, lambda3]])

    return sigma_gen

def get_tau(einval1, einval2, einval3):
    max_tau1 = 1 - abs(einval1)
    max_tau2 = 1 - abs(einval2)
    max_tau3 = 1 - abs(einval3)
    tau1 = max_tau1*(2*np.random.uniform(0,1)-1)
    tau2 = max_tau2*(2*np.random.uniform(0,1)-1)
    tau3 = max_tau3*(2*np.random.uniform(0,1)-1)

    return [tau1, tau2, tau3]

def z_eta(t: np.ndarray, l: np.ndarray):
    condition = (norm(t)**4 - 2*norm(t)**2 -
                 2*sum([(l[i]**2)*(2*(t[i]**2-norm(t)**2)) for i in range(3)])+
                 q(l))
    return condition

def q(e: np.ndarray):
    # e are the eigenvalues
    return (1+e[0]+e[1]+e[2])*(1+e[0]-e[1]-e[2])*(1-e[0]+e[1]-e[2])*(1-e[0]-e[1]+e[2])

def create_rotation(angles: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    "random rotation in PL form"
    # input np.random.normal(0,1,3)*0.06
    rotation = np.eye(4, dtype=complex)
    left = np.array([[ np.cos(angles[0]), np.sin(angles[0]), 0],
                     [-np.sin(angles[0]), np.cos(angles[0]), 0],
                     [                 0,                 0, 1]])
    mid = np.array([[1,                 0,                 0],
                    [0, np.cos(angles[1]), np.sin(angles[1])],
                    [0, -np.sin(angles[1]), np.cos(angles[1])]])
    right = np.array([[ np.cos(angles[2]), np.sin(angles[2]), 0],
                      [-np.sin(angles[2]), np.cos(angles[2]), 0],
                      [                 0,                 0, 1]])
    rotation[1:4,1:4] = left@mid@right

    return rotation

def gen_channel(r1, r2, ave, sigma):
    rand1 = np.random.normal(0,1,3)
    rand2 = np.random.normal(0,1,3)
    channel = create_rotation(rand1*r1)@gen_sigma(0.9, 1, ave, sigma)@\
              create_rotation(rand2*r2)
    return channel
```

An example run of a channel

```
gen_channel(0.05, 0.05, 0.98, 0.15)
```

would give for example

```
Out[140]: 
array([[ 1.        +0.j,  0.        +0.j,  0.        +0.j,
         0.        +0.j],
       [-0.05828008+0.j,  0.91805971+0.j,  0.14291751+0.j,
        -0.00946994+0.j],
       [-0.00509449+0.j, -0.14170308+0.j,  0.90034613+0.j,
        -0.11548884+0.j],
       [ 0.0467522 +0.j, -0.00851749+0.j,  0.11450963+0.j,
         0.90259637+0.j]])
```

Now if I want to create say 100 of these 4x4 matrix I'll have to use list comprehension i.e.

```
np.array([gen_channel(0.05, 0.05, 0.98, 0.15) for i in range(100)])
```

which will run through all the constraints comparison and create the 4x4 matrices one by one. Now my very original question was motivated by the fact that I want to vectorise them, so rather than comparing one value at a time, just generate an array of values using numpy broadcast and check the constraints such that I have a vectorise version of `gen_channel` which generates 100 such 4x4 matrices without the need of list comprehension. The list comprehension way contains the repeated use of generating a single random number which leads to a bottleneck in its runspeed. What I want to do is just generate arrays of random numbers, do those checks, then generate array of 4x4 channels so as to reduce the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could draw a large sample from the original distribution, then determine which entries lie in the correct range, and then draw from that:

```
# parameters
ave, sigma = 0,1
minimum, maximum = 0.9, 1

# draw sample and specify which entries are ok
a = np.random.normal(ave, sigma, 100000)
index = (a > minimum) & (a < maximum)

# draw from subset
np.random.choice(a[index], 1000, replace=False)
```

Using timeit

on the above code:

```
%%timeit -r 10 -n 10 
2.51 ms ± 87.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)
```

on the original in a loop:

```
%%timeit -r 10 -n 10

for i in range(1000):
    gen_truncated(0.9,1, 0, 1)

88.5 ms ± 1.24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Would this reduce the overhead of having to call my function `1000` times?So long as I don't draw too big of the full sample? What if there aren't enough elements within the full sample which fulfills the condition, and won't be enough to form my subset?

Comment: @user3613025 see the edit. I suppose if you are worried about the number of samples, you can check if the sum of  `index` is at least the length of your subset.

Comment: it looks exactly like what I want but I want to make sure it works with my whole algorithm before I accept your answer

Comment: please see my updated question, I'm sorry if my problem has become more complicated that it was originally.